Strongswan: can't ping anything
I know this question popped up many times in the bast but my situation is different as I'm using v5 and swanctl config.
connections {
    hscnsc {
        local_addrs  = 79.173.161.44
        remote_addrs = 195.206.176.xx
        local {
            auth = psk
            id = 79.173.161.44
        }
        remote {
            auth = psk
            id = 195.206.176.xx
        }
        children {
            net-net {
            mark_out = 10
        mark_in = 10
                local_ts  = 192.168.100.0/24
                remote_ts = 10.0.0.0/8,155.231.0.0/16
                esp_proposals = aes256-sha256-modp2048
            }
        }
        version = 2
        proposals = aes256-sha256-modp2048
        reauth_time = 86400
        rekey_time = 14400
        dpd_delay = 30
        dpd_timeout = 60
    }
}
secrets {
    ike-hscn {
        secret = StrongSecret
        id-0 = 79.173.161.44
        id-1 = 195.206.176.xx
    }
}

ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 1c:98:ec:15:62:a0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp2s0f0
    inet 79.173.161.44/29 brd 79.173.161.47 scope global eno1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::1e98:ecff:fe15:62a0/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eno2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 1c:98:ec:15:62:a1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp2s0f1
    inet 192.168.100.254/24 brd 192.168.100.255 scope global eno2
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::1e98:ecff:fe15:62a1/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: eno3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 1c:98:ec:15:62:a2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp2s0f2
5: eno4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 1c:98:ec:15:62:a3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp2s0f3
6: tailscale0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1280 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none
    inet 100.89.208.94/32 scope global tailscale0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fd7a:115c:a1e0::8901:d05e/128 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::9af1:fe18:3544:2a94/64 scope link stable-privacy
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:c4:dc:5b:c0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:c4ff:fedc:5bc0/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

I also have install_routes = yes in the /etc/strongswan.d/charon.conf, so
ip rule list
0:  from all lookup local
218:    from all fwmark 0xa lookup main
219:    from all fwmark 0xa lookup main
220:    from all lookup 220
5210:   from all fwmark 0x80000/0xff0000 lookup main
5230:   from all fwmark 0x80000/0xff0000 lookup default
5250:   from all fwmark 0x80000/0xff0000 unreachable
5270:   from all lookup 52
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default

ip route show table 220
10.0.0.0/8 via 79.173.161.41 dev eno1 proto static src 192.168.100.254
155.231.0.0/16 via 79.173.161.41 dev eno1 proto static src 192.168.100.254

this is on  Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)

You've configured mark_in|out. Is the traffic you are sending actually marked like that?
